# Using sidekiq/redistogo with heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I followed the sideqik gem tutorial docs and heroku Redistogo addon docs

**initializers/sidekiq.rb:**

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redistogo:xxx.redistogo.com:10076/' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redistogo:xxx.redistogo.com:10076/' }
end
```

**app/workers/hard_woker.rb:**

```
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(shop_domain, webhook)
   #performing stuffs
end
```

**Webhook I am putting into background job (trying to at least):**

```
class OrdersCreateJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(shop_domain:, webhook:)
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)
    shop.with_shopify_session do
      HardWorker.perform_async(shop_domain, webhook)
    end
  end
end
```

**Procfile:**

```
hardworker: bundle exec sidekiq -t 25
```

There are no errors in console.

Is something wrong here, did I miss something?

**My queue:**

```
irb(main):003:0> Sidekiq::Queue.all
=> [#<Sidekiq::Queue:0x000055b53a2d0920 @name="default", @rname="queue:default">]
```

I assume this means nothing is in the queue?

My goal is to take all my my CreateOrderWebhook code (which is almost 500 lines) into a background job to put less strain on the app and allow webhooks /prevent webhooks from being blocked

Comment: Don't hardcode your Redis URL. Use the provided ENV variable `heroku config` will provide it. Heroku doesn't pick up `hardworker`. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile for what supported process types it supports.

Comment: I did also add it to the config.  Does hardcoding it override it

Comment: Can you provide the entire contents of your Procfile?

Comment: I only added `hardworker: bundle exec sidekiq -t 25` ... there is nothing else atm

Comment: this might be stupid but looks like i needed to turn on the workeer wthin heorku.  also using t -25 went over the redis.  Using c -2 works....

Comment: @uno you should answer your own question below :)